# Modify object members inside array in Ionic with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops, ionic-framework

I have my array
myData= "1|N|BK1||MATH|1890.00|2100.00|1: 2|N|BK2||SCIENCE|1520.00|1790.00|1: "

I need to modify this myData values as below:

```
myFinalArray=   
[
        {
         "p_s.no": "3",
                 "p_ebook": "N",
         "p_id": "BK1",
                 "p_ebooktitle": "",
                 "p_name": "MATH",
                 "p_cprice": "1890.00",
                 "p_lprice": "2100.00",
                 "p_Q": "1"
        },
        {
         "p_s.no": "3",
                 "p_ebook": "N",
         "p_id": "BK2",
                 "p_ebooktitle": "",
                 "p_name": "SCIENCE",
                 "p_cprice": "1890.00",
                 "p_lprice": "2100.00",
                 "p_Q": "1"
        }
    ]
```

I am trying to split the values with ":" & then "|" and loop through each values to add a text for each values. Finally pushing it to a variable. I feel there might be some better ways to achieve this. Please help me with your ideas.

Sample code below:

```
this.myDataArray = this.myData.split(": ")
this.myDataArray.forEach(element=>
{
this.myNewDataArray=element.split("|")
for (let i = 0; i < this.myNewDataArray.length; i++) 
{
if(i===0){
this.temp = ('"p_s.no"' + ':' + '"' + this.myNewDataArray[i] + '"');    
}
else if (i === 1) {
this.temp = this.temp + "," + ('"p_ebook"' + ':' + '"' + this.myNewDataArray[i] + '"');
}
else if (i === 2) {
this.temp = this.temp + "," + ('"p_id"' + ':' + '"' + this.myNewDataArray[i] + '"');
}
else if (i === 3) {
this.temp = this.temp + "," + ('"p_ebooktitle"' + ':' + '"' + this.myNewDataArray[i] + '"');
}
else if (i === 4) {
this.temp = this.temp + "," + ('"p_name"' + ':' + '"' + this.myNewDataArray[i] + '"');
}
else if (i === 5) {
this.temp = this.temp + "," + ('"p_cprice"' + ':' + '"' + this.myNewDataArray[i] + '"');
}
else if (i === 6) {
this.temp = this.temp + "," + ('"p_lprice"' + ':' + '"' + this.myNewDataArray[i] + '"');
}
else if (i === 7) {
this.temp = this.temp + "," + ('"p_Q"' + ':' + '"' + this.myNewDataArray[i] + '"');
}   
}
if (this.temp !== "") {
this.myFinalArray.push("{" + this.temp + "}");        
      }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your object keys in an array so you can iterate the array to match each property name and value in an object within a map() of the split data string

```js
const keys = ["p_s.no","p_ebook","p_id","p_ebooktitle","p_name","p_cprice","p_lprice","p_Q"];

const myData= "1|N|BK1||MATH|1890.00|2100.00|1: 2|N|BK2||SCIENCE|1520.00|1790.00|1: ";

const res = myData.split(': ')
                  .filter(s => !!s.trim())
                  .map(s => s.split('|').reduce((a,c,i) => (a[keys[i]] = c, a),{}))
                  
console.log(res)
```